# how to handle responsive form layout without media queries

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, media-queries, responsive

I have a form layout as below.
Can I get some suggestions how best to handle the layout for this such that:

- On a mobile screen if the text is "too long" (basically would NOT allow too elements to fit) then it would break the form into two lines
- on a desktop the two elements would just be in the same row.

Can I **avoid** using media queries and somehow get the text to never wrap? One idea would be to replace all the spaces with non-breaking spaces, which might somehow force the second whole item onto a new line.

CSS always takes so much freaking tweaking time!

[image: layout item]

Comment: or I could wrap each item and radio box in a div and use some type of flexbox layout?

Comment: you can put each item in a separate div and make their parent flex, and flex-wrap: wrap; it makes them to go in two lines when there is no enough space.

Answer (score 1):

here it is example for you it will help:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image">...</div>
  <div class="contant">...</div>
</div>

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cont .contant,
.container .image {
/* breakpoint is your 12em change. */
  flex: 1 0 12em;
}
```

and you can use property of 
max-width:100%;
min-width:50% 
in your text